# Parse org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate in Java.util.Date

Tags: java, javascript, date

I'm trying to parse a date that i get from JavaScript script evaluated with rhino library into java.util.Date, can i convert a org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate into a java.util.Date ?

If convert NativeDate into a string with the Context.tostring method i get a date in the following format :

```
Wed Oct 12 2011 16:17:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

How can i parse this string date representation in to a java.util.Date object ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Rhino use

`context.jsToJava(nativeDateObj, Date.class);`

Comment: In case anyone wondered, that is a static method, you don't need access to the script context.

Answer (score 5):

Bvesco's answer works well. However doing this the other way round (java to js) is not entirely as simple - `Context.javaTojs()` does not work for dates. I eventually found the solution [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/browse_thread/thread/c747e3727e17f636?pli=1) - use the javascript constructor:

```
Object js = context.newObject(scope, "Date", new Object[] {date.getTime()});
```

The above post also mentioned the following alternative to convert a date from js to java (I haven't confirmed this):

```
Date date = new Date((long) ScriptRuntime.toNumber(s));
```

Comment: Using the javascript constructor works when going to JS.  Thanks!

Comment: Might you help me with my problem. I am trying to apply your solution but I don't know how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192485/using-rhino-instead-of-scriptengine-to-run-javascript-code-in-java

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried;?

```
java.sql.Date.valueOf("date string");
```

Comment: The method valueOf(String) is undefined for the type Date

Comment: Undefined? The method exists in SE Java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: The method still exists in 7: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf(java.lang.String

Comment: ok, the method is in the java.sql.Date package, but it doesn't work, if i try to parse that string i get : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. HAve you tried to parse the string in the post ?

Comment: it should be obvious that you will need to parse the string somewhat