# OrientDb Graph get Date in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, datetime, orientdb, rhino

I stored date in property in some edges in graph database.

Now I want to get this date that I can compare it with date in javascript function.

This is example of edge structure:

```
{
        "@type": "d",
        "@rid": "#24:27592",
        "@version": 1,
        "@class": "Edge_Bus",
        "out": "#22:2643",
        "in": "#22:3946",
        "busId": 10736921,
        "departureTime": "2016-11-08 19:40:00",
        "@fieldTypes": "out=x,in=x,trainId=l,departureTime=t"
    }
```

I want to get `departureTime`.

I try:

```
var val = edge.field('departureTime');
```

and

```
var val = new Date(edge.field('departureTime'));
```

I suppose that `val` is type of `java.util.Date` and when I try to compare it with standard Date in Javascript (`var searchDateTime = new Date("2016-11-08 12:00:00");`) I got wrong comparison result.

I was tried:

```
val > searchDateTime
val.getTime() > searchDateTime.getTime()
```

I found some answer on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.tech.js-engine.rhino/x0fjcn4X9jY

And

[Parse org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate in Java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741699/parse-org-mozilla-javascript-nativedate-in-java-util-date)

Is this suppouse is ok (because OrientDB has Rhino engine) and is it this right way to get Date from OrientDb in Javascript function?
Thank you :)

Comment: If someone will have same problem, I resolved this on this way, that I create `var sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
var dateString = "2016-11-22 12:00:00";
var searchDateTime = sdf.parse(dateString);`  For `var val = edge.field('departureTime');` `var` is `java.util.Date` type.